# parse image urls from jsonstring

Tags: android, json

I have one parameter in `json` data called "content" from which I want to get image urls and display that images in `ImageView` dynamically.

I have tried `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes and I am getting firstimage url correctly but could not able to make out logic for more than one image url.

content is as follows:

```
"content":"<p style=\"text-align: justify;\">Huawei India has expanded the reach and availability of their online-only Honor smartphone series.<img class=\"aligncenter size-full wp-image-14114\" src=\"http:\/\/imageurl.jpg\"\/><p style=\"text-align: justify;\">Huawei India, along with it, has also confirmed that Honor smartphones will get the Android 6.0 Marshmallow updates with other devices in the upcoming year in the month of February.<\/p><img class=\"aligncenter size-full wp-image-14115\" src=\"http:\/\/second Image url.png\" \/>\n<p style=\"text-align: justify;\">The new update is likely to get Huawei Honor users to be excited, if you are a Honor smartphone user do share your feelings in the comment box below.<\/p>\n"
```

I am getting first image url as follows:

```
String imgRegex = "<img[^>]+src\\s*=\\s*['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^>]*>";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(imgRegex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(posts.getExcerpt());
        String src = "";
        if (m.find()) {
            src = m.group(1);
            imgPost.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.v("groupCount : ",""+m.groupCount());
            //Toast.makeText(this,"pattern : "+src,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Picasso.with(this)
                    .load(""+src)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .into(imgPost);
        }
```

Any idea how to get all image urls using `PatternMatcher` class or anything else??

Comment: try this: JSoup in android

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that once you get the json string the content in HTML.
You could use JSoup to extract data it is very easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `while( m.find()){ ... }` instead of the conditional